# How to set the socket timeout for a DB2 Universal JDBC Driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, settimeout, websphere-6.1

How to set the socket timeout for a DB2 (9.7) Universal JDBC Driver DataSource on WebSphere Application Server 6.1? I've tried adding the `blockingReadConnectionTimeout` property as [this IBM Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21590014) says, but the problem is still there. Is there another way to set this property? Should I set it within the Java application code?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the timeout on the Connection pool setting through the Admin Console.

```
Data sources > Default > Connection pools
```

Specifically, there is a property called Connection timeout.  We have ours set to 60.

Comment: I think this is a upper lever property, the socket timeout must be set at the DB driver level. I'm working on that.